# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/netflix/curator/RetryPolicy when integrating kinesis spout with storm

Tags: apache-zookeeper

Trying to connect my storm topology with the kinesis spout and getting following exception

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/netflix/curator/RetryPolicy
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.stormspout.state.zookeeper.ZookeeperStateManager.activate(ZookeeperStateManager.java:104) ~[kinesis-storm-spout-1.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.stormspout.KinesisSpout.activate(KinesisSpout.java:125) ~[kinesis-storm-spout-1.1.0.jar:na]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__3373$fn__3388$fn__3417.invoke(executor.clj:563) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
    at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__464.invoke(util.clj:463) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) [clojure-1.5.0.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.netflix.curator.RetryPolicy
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Posting your code will help you getting good answers!

Answer (score 1):

Copy all the kafka, zookeper, storm, scala jar files into `storm/lib` folder, and then try again.

That error means `curator-client-1.2.4.jar` is not compatible, so download an older version and add it in `strom/l`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using maven try this so you dont have to handpick dependent jar

```
<build>
 <plugins>
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <archive>
      <manifest>
        <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
      </manifest>
    </archive>
    <descriptorRefs>
      <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
    </descriptorRefs>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```